# How to solve libpng function already defined error?

Tags: c++, opencv, itk

I use ITK-4.11 and OpenCV-3.2 together in one of my c++ project, when I compile the project, I get an error that says:

> Error  1   error LNK2005: png_get_uint_31 already defined in itkpng-4.11.lib(pngrutil.obj)"

Both of my ITK and OpenCV are built using Multi-threaded DLL (/MD), then, what should I do to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, I solved that exact problem by using /FORCE linker option. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085050/how-to-ignore-lnk2005-lnk1169).

Comment: Thank you Dženan, using /FORCE in visual studio perfectly solved the problem.

Comment: Also, someone else ran into this issue recently and proposed a patch to fix it on ITK's part: http://review.source.kitware.com/#/c/22282/

Comment: Yes Dženan. Adding a line "#define png_get_uint_31 itk_png_get_uint_31" in the ITK file "Modules/ThirdParty/PNG/src/itkpng/itk_png_mangle.h" is definitely a better solution! Thank you again.

Comment: Besides accepting my answer, you can also up-vote it.